# Updating a react control built from multiple sources

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I would like to build an editable table that contains columns that are from multiple subtrees of the graphql data returned by relay.

I have a control that creates an intermediate object for each of the rows from the relay data and stores the list in state.

The problem I have is that when the data which I built the intermediate object from changes then the editable table needs to know about it.

Is this correct ? Is there some other way to do this ?

The controls that own the data the table is built from are not related, would the only way to do this then be the global event system solution mentioned in the docs ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Relay for this app? (I noticed the tag). What is the GraphQL schema? What is the relevant component fragment, and what have you tried to do already when implementing the mutation?

Comment: Hi, sorry I completely reworded the question to make it less specific. Thanks